# 2D Actor Picking in VTK-7 with Python

Tags: python, vtk

I have a simple program in Python-VTK(7) that has three disks in 2D that can be clicked and moved around.

I do this by making a custom interactor style, in which I store the selected element on `LeftButtonClick` event, change position of the previously selected element on `MouseMove` event and set the selected element to `None` on `LeftButtonRelease` event.

Here's the complete VTK code which (ideally) should do that:

```
import vtk

class CustomInteractor(vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera):

    def __init__(self, renderer, renWin):
        self.AddObserver('LeftButtonPressEvent', self.OnLeftButtonDown)
        self.AddObserver('LeftButtonReleaseEvent', self.OnLeftButtonRelease)
        self.AddObserver('MouseMoveEvent', self.OnMouseMove)

        self.renderer = renderer
        self.chosenPiece = None
        self.renWin = renWin

    def OnLeftButtonRelease(self, obj, eventType):
        self.chosenPiece = None
        vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera.OnLeftButtonUp(self)

    def OnLeftButtonDown(self, obj, eventType):
        clickPos = self.GetInteractor().GetEventPosition()

        picker = vtk.vtkPropPicker()
        picker.Pick(clickPos[0], clickPos[1], 0, self.renderer)
        actor = picker.GetActor2D()

        self.chosenPiece = actor

        vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera.OnLeftButtonDown(self)

    def OnMouseMove(self, obj, eventType):
        if self.chosenPiece is not None:

            mousePos = self.GetInteractor().GetEventPosition()

            self.chosenPiece.SetPosition(mousePos[0], mousePos[1])

            self.renWin.Render()
        else :
            vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera.OnMouseMove(self)


def buildDiskActor(inner_radius = 10, outer_radius = 20, position = (100, 20), color = (1, 1, 1)):
    disk = vtk.vtkDiskSource()
    disk.SetInnerRadius(inner_radius)
    disk.SetOuterRadius(outer_radius)
    disk.SetRadialResolution(100)
    disk.SetCircumferentialResolution(100)
    disk.Update()

    mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper2D()
    mapper.SetInputConnection(disk.GetOutputPort())

    actor = vtk.vtkActor2D()
    actor.SetMapper(mapper)

    actor.SetPosition(position[0], position[1])

    actor.GetProperty().SetColor(color)

    return actor

ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(ren)
renWin.SetSize(600, 600)

elements = [
    buildDiskActor(position = (200, 400), color=(1, 0, 0)),
    buildDiskActor(position = (400, 400), color=(0, 1, 0)),
    buildDiskActor(position = (300, 200), color=(0, 0, 1)),
]

for actor in elements:
    ren.AddActor(actor)

iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)
inStyle = CustomInteractor(ren, renWin)
iren.SetInteractorStyle(inStyle)

renWin.Render()
iren.Start()
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

i.e., whichever disk I pick, only the green one is selected by the `vtkPropPicker`.

For some reason, things work as expected when I use Python2-VTK6.3.0 instead of Python3-VTK7. Is this a bug in VTK7? Or is the implementation changed in some way? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VTK 7 switched to a new rendering backend. In 7.0, the rendering backend has a bug with picking 2D actors.

The bug is fixed in 7.1; see [Kitware/VTK@`5559c11`](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/commit/5559c11b3ecc1a03206014c126eefe10c7c3e3cc).